# Creating a class to get all buttons delegates

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a `UIViewController` class called , `classA` . This class is connected to `buttons` outlets of its connected view (from storyboard ).

What i would like to do , is to create another `classB` , that will handle all the buttons actions.
My question is, how can i set the delegates of a button in `classA` to be handled in `classB`, and how i make `classB` to be alive for all that time.

I was thinking about this .

in classA :(the main view controller that have the buttons outlets )

```
ClassB *buttonsResponder=[[classB alloc]init]; //initialize buttons class
  [self.button addTarget:buttonsResponder action:@selector(do:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

My main problem is, when classB handle the action, and lets say he has to open some mail composer view controller, how can classB open that mail composer "inside" classA view ? or even some `UIView` that i want to show in classA , but **from** `classB`

I was thinking of sending a pointer to the current view controller as an argument of the button, but i dont know how, and if it will work :

> [self.button addTarget:buttonsResponder action:@selector(do:and
>   controller pointer?) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

Comment: Keep a strong reference of classB in classA. Make instance of classB as a instanceVariable or property of classA otherwise it will be deallocated

Comment: thanks, see my edit please, i didn't mention my main problem .

Comment: i would suggest you to rethink the idea of `classB` here. If the buttons are part of `classA` its better to handle the actions there only, otherwise you could have a strong reason to do that. Anything like that?

Comment: your right but these buttons are the same for many views, and so i dont want to recode their actions again and again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to keep ClassB alive in ClassA instance is make it a private property in class extension:

```
// In CalssA
@property (nonatomic, strong) ClassB *buttonsResponder;
```

You need to allocate it somewhere, viewDidLoad is good place:

```
self.buttonsResponder = [[classB alloc]init];
```

and in the same method you can make it a button(s) delegate:

```
[self.button addTarget:self.buttonsResponder action:@selector(do:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

// Extended

If you want to present another view controller from your ClassB you can create property to hold weak reference to classA in classB:

```
// In ClassB.h
@property (nonatomic, weak) ClassA *myClassA;
```

Pass a reference to of classA when you initialise classB in viewDidLoad:

```
// In ClassA.m
self.buttonsResponder = [[classB alloc]init];
self.buttonsResponder.myClassA = self;
```

And when you want to present another view controller you can do it from classB:

```
[self.myClassA presentViewController:...];
```

Comment: Thanks, see my edit please .  my problem , is that if in respond to that action i would like to present another view controller, how can i do that from this classB ? see my edit .

Comment: @Curnelious please see extended answer.

Comment: thanks ,this seems like a better approach than open it in the the root view controller (right? )

Comment: also , i have to set MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate , i guess i will not do that in classB right ? so classB will set back classA to be responder to the mail composer ?

Comment: @Curnelious it's really up to you. You can set the delegate to classB: delegate = self; or you can set it up to classA: delegate = self.myClassA. Choose one which will work best for you.

Comment: another problem that occurs, if classB is NSObject, than  MFMailComposeViewController will produce errors. i wonder now about the whole approach

Comment: It shouldn't be an issue. I guessing that you need to make a strong pointer to mail object and remember to set up class to conform to mail delegate.

Answer (score 1):

> [self.button addTarget:self.buttonsResponder action:@selector(do:)
>   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

If you want to present another viewcontroller from buttonsResponder:

```
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: cool thats a nice approach ! but he must be always my root view at the time. what about passing the current controller as pointer ?

Comment: and something else, mail composer has to set and register to delegate, how and who is register to get the delegate ? its not going to be class B i guess ?

Comment: well.. in this case.. yes. it's better to pass it as a pointer